# How to simplify an equation by using min amount of if block in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, math, design-patterns, switch-statement

I have the following equation and I am thinking that there may be an approach to simplify it:

```
(A, B, C) = (x, y, z), if (0 <= q < 5)
            (y, x, z), if (5 <= q < 10)
            (z, x ,y), if (10 <= q < 15)
            (z, y, x), if (15 <= q < 20)
            (y, z, x), if (20 <= q < 25)
            (x, z, y), if (25 <= q < 30)
```

Is there a better way to write 6 condition for this equation?

```
if(0 <= q && q < 1)
    A = x; B 0 y; C = z;
else if(1 <= q && q < 2)
   ...
```

Comment: You have exactly one line that mentions `y` twice, every other line mentions each variable once. Is that a typo? Also: what should happen when `q` is  < 0 or > 6?

Comment: There is no situation for `q is < 0 or > 6`, forget it. ANd yes, I updated the equation there is a problem with line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a switch statement to return an object with the values. Here I am using a `record` as an immutable class.  It could also be a regular class.

```
record Data<T> (T A, T B, T C) {}

Data<Integer> d = getValues(10.6, 10,20,30);
System.out.println(d);
Data<String> d2 = getValues(9.3, "One","Two","Three");
System.out.println(d2);
```

prints

```
Data[A=30, B=10, C=20]
Data[A=Two, B=One, C=Three]
```

- casting `q` to an `int` will select the correct case
- then just return the object associated with the value of `q`
- Exception will be thrown if `q` is out of range.

```
public static <T> Data<T> getValues(double q, T x, T y, T z) {           
   return switch((int)(q/5)) {
         case 0 -> new Data<>(y,x,z);
         case 1 -> new Data<>(y,x,z);
         case 2 -> new Data<>(z,x,y);
         case 3 -> new Data<>(z,y,x);
         case 4 -> new Data<>(y,z,x);
         case 5 -> new Data<>(x,z,y);
         default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument out of range q = " + q);
   
     };
}
```

Comment: BTW `default` can also throw an exception (e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and voted up. Actually `q` values are not 1,2,3 and I posted is for simplicity. So, could you have a look at the updated question (`q >= x and < y` parts) and suggest a solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jonathan Not a problem. Just divide `q` by 5 to get 0 thru 5 inclusive.   I cast to an `int` in case it is a double.  I updated the answer.

Comment: **Fascinating!..** Thanks a lot, it seems to work properly. Just wondered what is the purpose of `<T>` in front of `Data<T>``in the `getValues` method. Could you please explain it? I do not make it work with this.

Comment: It is a generic type to allow the method to work for any type .  So  `A,B,C`, and `x,y,z` could be any type. `Strings. Doubles`, etc. When I declared `Data<Integer>` that set the type of `Integer` for this example.  I updated it to show how Strings could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the x, y, and z values are somewhat constant, you could create a Map that translate the q value to a particular assignment of A, B, C.

```
Map<Long,Assignment> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, new Assignment(x,y,z));
map.put(1, new Assignment(y,x,z));
...
map.put(5, new Assignment(x,z,y));

public Assignment getAssignment(double q) {
  // out of range values of q return null
  return map.get((long)Math.floor(q));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and voted up. Actually `q` values are not 1,2,3 and I posted is for simplicity. So, could you have a look at the updated question (`q >= x and < y` parts) and suggest a solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a simple data structure:

```
public class Foo {
    private static final List<Foo> library;
    static {
        library = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        library.add(new Foo(x, y, z, 0, 1));
        library.add(new Foo(y, x, z, 1, 2));
        library.add(new Foo(z, x, y, 2, 3));
        library.add(new Foo(z, y, x, 3, 4));
        library.add(new Foo(y, z, x, 4, 5));
        library.add(new Foo(x, z, y, 5, 6));
    };
    public static Foo get(double val) {
        for(Foo foo : library) {
            if(foo.lower <= val && foo.upper > val)
                return foo;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public final Object A,B,C;
    private final double lower,upper;
    private Foo(Object A, Object B, Object C, double lower, double upper) {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
        this.C = C;
        this.lower = lower;
        this.upper = upper;
    }
}
```

Then you can acces your values like this

```
Foo foo = Foo.get(1.5d);
foo.A; // y
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and voted up. Actually `q` values are not 1,2,3 and I posted is for simplicity. So, could you have a look at the updated question (`q >= x and < y` parts) and suggest a solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jonathan if you understand the posted answer, you will see that the two last values of `Foo` are the lower and upper bounds... so you just need to change these values when the `Foo`s are being created (e.g. instead of `new Foo(y, x, z, 1, 2)` it could be `new Foo(y, x, z, 5, 10)`)